# Confused about JSX syntax

Tags: jsx

All:

I am pretty new to React and JSX, when I try it like:

```
render(){
    return (
        {
            (function(){
                return <div>Hello, world</div>
            })()
        }
    )       
}
```

It gives me error like:

```
Syntax error: C:/Temp/web/path/src/line.js: Unexpected token (26:4)

  24 |      return (
  25 |          {
> 26 |              (function(){
     |              ^
  27 |                                  return <div>Hello, world</div>
  28 |                              })()
  29 |          }
```

@ ./src/App.js 16:12-29

But after I wrap this function into a `<div>` tag, it works, I thought `{}` is used to interpret what inside, but why it has to work with `<div>` tag?

How can I do this without wrapping a div

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Inside return in your render function should be what you want to output.

```
render(){
    return (
        <div>Hello, world</div> 
    );
}
```

Every render function needs one main enclosing tag. So:

```
render(){
    return (
        <div>Hello, world</div> 
        <div>You are great!</div> 
    );
}
```

will not work.  You would need:

```
render(){
    return (
      <div>
        <div>Hello, world</div> 
        <div>You are great!</div> 
      </div>
    );
}
```

Also, you are correct when you say {} is used to interpret what inside when placed in jsx markup, except it is used for simple expressions. If you need to define functions, do it outside the render function.

```
this.name = 'Kuan';

boldName(){
  return (
    <b>{this.name}</b>
  );
}

render(){
    return (
        <div>Hello, world</div> 
        <div>You are {this.boldName()}</div> 
    );
}
```

or specifically for your question:

```
myRenderFunction(){
    return <div>Hello, world</div>
}

render(){
    return (
        {this.myRenderFunction()}
    )       
}
```

Comment: @Kuan, I added something at the end that I think exactly covers your example.  I hope the explanations are also helpful.  Is there anything more you need to accept the answer?

Answer (score 0):

```
return (
    {
        (function(){
            return <div>Hello, world</div>
        })()
    }
)
```

i think this is basic syntax problem, at the `{` jsx expects `xml structure`, if you need to call that function inside the render, try to do it `using normal javascript`, please try this

```
return (
    (function(){
        return <div>Hello, world</div>
    })()
)
```